# Finding MySQL near-duplicates across two columns using wildcards

Tags: mysql

I have a table with id, first_name and last_name columns. I'd like to get a listing  of rows where last_name and the first character of first_name are duplicated. I am groping my way around and have a sense that there is a COUNT('WHERE') in there, but can't quite get to it.

In essence, I'm looking for possible duplicates. So, from this subset:

```
+------+-----------+-----------+-------------+------------+
| id   | firstName | lastName  | dateOfBirth | createdOn  |
+------+-----------+-----------+-------------+------------+
|  143 | Susie     | Wong      | 2015-12-01  | 2016-07-11 |
| 1268 | Dale      | Armstrong | 2017-01-01  | 2017-01-04 |
| 1435 | Olive     | Armstrong | 1941-03-11  | 2017-03-08 |
| 2013 | Timotini  | Attilio   | 1932-01-01  | 2017-08-21 |
| 2014 | Olinda    | Attilio   | 1938-01-01  | 2017-08-21 |
| 3076 | Sue       | Armstrong | 1951-06-01  | 2018-06-22 |
| 3079 | Susan     | Armstrong | 1951-09-15  | 2018-06-22 |
+------+-----------+-----------+-------------+------------+
```

I would like a query that returns only 3076 and 3079 (Sue and Susan Armstrong) based on looking for a matching last name and a matching first initial, like so:

```
+------+-----------+-----------+-------------+------------+
| id   | firstName | lastName  | dateOfBirth | createdOn  |
+------+-----------+-----------+-------------+------------+
| 3076 | Sue       | Armstrong | 1951-06-01  | 2018-06-22 |
| 3079 | Susan     | Armstrong | 1951-09-15  | 2018-06-22 |
+------+-----------+-----------+-------------+------------+
```

Comment: Sample data and expected results would be helpful.  Perhaps you are looking for `left()`...

Comment: Updated as suggested, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one option using `exists` and `left`:

```
select *
from yourtable y
where exists (
  select 1
  from yourtable y2 
  where y.id != y2.id 
    and y.lastname = y2.lastname 
    and left(y.firstname,1) = left(y2.firstname,1)
)
```

- [Sample Fiddle Demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/rT4vSFFsiUk1V1BLevhdaX/0)

Comment: Perfect! I had to add an "ORDER BY y.lastname" to the query to make it work, but otherwise this did exactly what I needed. Thanks so much, and now I have a good starting understanding of left()!

Answer (score 0):

**Duplicates of `last_name`**

```
SELECT id, first_name, last_name, COUNT(*) c 
FROM table 
GROUP BY last_name 
HAVING c > 1;
```

For grouping by the first character in `first_name`, try playing with [left()](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_left.asp) function

Comment: I tried this, but GROUP BY doesn't work, as I need to see the separate individual records for all those whose last names match (and whose first initial of first name matches as well). This query returns a count of multiple-appearing last names with a miscellaneous first name attached.